# Unterstanding a wsdl document what is meant by <wsdl:output .. name .. message>

Tags: wsdl

This is my java code

```
public class TestClient
{
    public int a=55;    

    public void setname(String nameeey){

    }

    public int foo(){
      return 55;
    }

    public String foo2(int value, int a2,double hool){
       return "2343";
    }
}
```

and this is the porttype of the wsdl doc

```
<wsdl:portType name="TestClientPortType">

  <wsdl:operation name="foo">
      <wsdl:input name="foo" message="tns:foo">
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="fooResponse" message="tns:fooResponse">
      </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>

  <wsdl:operation name="setname">
      <wsdl:input name="setname" message="tns:setname">
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="setnameResponse" message="tns:setnameResponse"> 
      </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>

  <wsdl:operation name="foo2">
      <wsdl:input name="foo2" message="tns:foo2"> 
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="foo2Response" message="tns:foo2Response"> 
      </wsdl:output>
  </wsdl:operation>

</wsdl:portType>
```

what does

```
<wsdl:output name="fooResponse" message="tns:fooResponse">
```

mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Services relate to messaging and their are various Message Exchange Patterns (MEPs). In the case of the foo operation, it is an IN-OUT pattern, or request/response (relating to the java method).

The input message is the request you are sending to the service and the output message is the response from the service. So the 'fooResponse' message is a wrapper around the integer return value.

Answer (score 0):

Check out these

http://www.w3schools.com/wsdl/wsdl_documents.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/wsdl/wsdl_ports.asp

Comment: It seems that the link is dead. I found this one: http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/ws_wsdl_documents.asp